# Message Driven Bean not consuming message after being deployed correctly

Tags: java, linux, jboss, ibm-mq, jboss-mdb

i have deployed mdb correctly and server log said that i have deployed successfully however i am still not able to consume message from websphere mq in the jboss container

**My activation config in my mdb**

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "ip_address"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "port"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "JAVA.CHANNEL"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "Q_PVF_BACKEND"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "TEST_MRIS_IIB")
    })
@ResourceAdapter(value="wmq.jmsra.rar")
```

**Jboss Server log**

```
08:40:38,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ikvEAR.ear"
08:40:38,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ikvEJB.jar"
08:40:38,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'mdb' with 'wmq.jmsra' resource adapter
08:40:38,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "ikvEAR.ear"
```

**Standalone-full.xml**

```
    ...
         <mdb>
              <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
              <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-wmq-strict-max-pool"/>
        </mdb>
...
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter>
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                        true
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="traceLevel">
                        6
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                        true
                    </config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/jboss/PVFConnectionFactory" pool-name="PVFConnectionFactory">
                            <config-property name="port">
                                port
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="channel">
                                SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="hostName">
                                ip_address
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="transportType">
                                CLIENT
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager">
                                TEST_MRIS_IIB
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/jboss/jobQueue" pool-name="jobQueue">
                            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                                TEST_MRIS_IIB
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                                Q_MRES_PSDS_ALL_MSG
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/jboss/backendQueue" pool-name="backendQueue">
                            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                                TEST_MRIS_IIB
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                                Q_PVF_BACKEND
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to name your resource adapter:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
```

I'm puzzled by:

```
Started message driven bean 'mdb' with 'wmq.jmsra' resource adapter
```

All of the resource adapters should have the name 'wmq.jmsra.rar'.  Does your deployments page on the JBoss web UI show your IBM MQ resource adapter?

Comment: I name my resource adapter but i still not able to consume message from the Websphere mq. 

`Started message driven bean 'mdb' with 'wmq.jmsra' resource adapter`

This is just the info that this mdb is deployed with this resource adapter.